# How to return an array from controller to view in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm trying to return an array from controller to view. Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()

        {
            TahakkukServicesClient client = new TahakkukServicesClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            MakbuzList[] liste = client.GetMakbuzListe(2);
            return View(liste);
        }

    }
}
```

So how can I display my array's values in my view?

Comment: I just love localised code... ;) One could write a super offensive question here and we wouldn't know it. :)

Comment: http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MakbuzList[]` "is" an `IEnumerable<MakbuzList>` (Note : nowadays, Generic lists / collections are usually preferred to arrays)

So you can strongly type your view like that

```
@model IEnumerable<MakbuzList>
```

and display values like this

```
@if (Model.Any()) {
  foreach (var makbuz in Model) {
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => makbuz.Property1)
  }
}
```

Comment: IIRC this will not work because the expression must always resolve the object to display starting from the model itself. I 'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Jon It won't work well with editorFor and binding (where you need a for loop), but I can tell you it's gonna be fine for DisplayFor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the view is already configured with

```
@model IList<MakbuzList>
```

Then you can simply do

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; ++i) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i]);
}
```

Comment: It does not work I get this error no extension method "Length"